# Intersection of sets of line segments

Tags: c++, geometry, intersection

There are two sets of segments M and N. There are requests to add segments to these sets. After each request, I need to print how many intersections are there in the total. How to do it in O(log|M|+log|N|)?

Comment: To be clear, you want to know how many segments in M intersect with segments in N, correct?  (two intersecting segments in M don't count towards the total count, correct?)

Comment: And these segments are in 2D space?  3D?  Or arbitrary?

Comment: @selbie Yes, they are 2D coordinates and two intersecting segments in M don't count towards the total count.